# Problem connecting Canon TS5060

Tags: drivers, printing, canon

I have been trying to get my Canon Pixma TS5060 working on 20.04.  I have got it to print images, but no text.  I know the printer is OK as I can print with it when on Windows 7 (the computer is dual boot).  The printer is connected via USB.  I have downloaded and installed cnijfilterw and scangearmp2.  Do I need a PPD file?  If so, where do I find it?
I am still learning, so full instructions are best, although I know sudo, apt-get, and install.

alan@alan-HPProDesk-600-G1-TWR:~$ lpstat -l -e
TS5000_series_alan_HPProDesk_600_G1_TWR permanent ipp://localhost/printers/TS5000_series_alan_HPProDesk_600_G1_TWR file:///dev/null
TS5000_series_alan_HPProDesk_600_G1_TWR_alan_HPProDesk_600_G1 network none ipps://TS5000_series_alan_HPProDesk_600_G1_TWR%20%40%20alan-HPProDesk-600-G1._ipps._tcp.local/cups

I have run the troubleshoot program with no success.  I have saved it can send it separately if requested.
Any assistance appreciated.

Comment: I have tried using different colours for the text, but no luck.
Also, after numerous attempt to load drivers etc using different methods, I fear there may be a mess of drivers and apps related to in the printer area.  Is there a way of cleaning it all up so I can do a fresh install?  There are 4 (that's right, four) different printers appear when I open the settings gui dialog.  I keep on removing them, but they keep coming back.  That's why I think I need a cleanout.  Any help appreciated.

Comment: I have run the troubleshoot dialog.  The following is the result.